# Parsing JSON to Map

Tags: json, typescript

After making a GET request to an API in TS, I am not able to correctly parse the response. The map in the `products` field of `MapDetails` is parsed as an object instead of a map. Appreciate any help with getting this parsed correctly

Here is the JSON response

```
{
    "New Arrivals":{
        "url":"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1595950653106-6c9ebd614d3a?q=80\u0026w=2574\u0026auto=format\u0026fit=crop\u0026ixlib=rb-4.0.3\u0026ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
        "filters":{"category":"New Arrivals","gender":"Unisex"},
        "products":{
            "Men":{
                "Accessories":{"category":"All Accessories","gender":"Men"},
                "Gifts":{"category":"Gifts","gender":"Men"}
            },
            "Women":{
                "Accessories":{"category":"All Accessories","gender":"Women"},
                "Gifts":{"category":"Gifts","gender":"Women"}
            }
        }
    },
    "Women":{
        "url":"https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1675186049409-f9f8f60ebb5e?q=80\u0026w=2574\u0026auto=format\u0026fit=crop\u0026ixlib=rb-4.0.3\u0026ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
        "filters":{"category":"All Products","gender":"Women"},
        "products":{
            "Accessories":{
                "All Accessories":{"category":"All Accessories","gender":"Men"},
                "Bags":{"category":"Bags","gender":"Men"}
            },
            "Clothes":{
                "All Clothes":{"category":"All Clothes","gender":"Women"},
                "Bottoms":{"category":"Bottoms","gender":"Women"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's how I am trying to parse the API response

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(parsed => new Map<string, MapDetails>(Object.entries(parsed)))
```

`MapDetails` implementation

```
export interface ShopDetails {
    category: string;
    gender: string;

}

export interface MapDetails {
    url: string;
    filters: ShopDetails;
    products : Map<string, Map<string, ShopDetails>>
}
```

Comment: Does this question require knowledge of react to answer? If so please tag it as such. If not, please [edit] the code to remove references to react and replace it with TS-only code.  Additionally, make sure that your code is a standalone [mre] without references to private/missing/third-party things, so that people can easily copy and paste it into their own IDEs and get to work on it. Right now there seems to be a whole bunch of references to undeclared things like `ShopDetails` which we don't have access to. You should define them for us, or even better, remove them.

Comment: I just edited the original post - let me know if this helps. `ShopDetails` is mentioned in the `MapDetails` implementation section as well

Comment: It still seems like you need to know about react (`useState`, etc), right? Do you mind if I tag it as such so that people who know it will maybe see?

Comment: Looks like I missed that. Use state isn't of any importance in this question. I'm just focusing on turning json data to a map, ultimately

Comment: Okay, thanks, this is close enough to a [mre] for me to use it. So you need to do the conversion yourself, at each depth for which an object should be turned to a map, as shown in [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NloJOw). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?